# Restarting a function once condition returns True

Tags: python, while-loop

Trying my hand at writing a very simple Game of Chance game on Codecademy while working through their Python course. I was doing ok (I think) for a while and the code returned what I expected it to, but now it feels I'm stuck and googling things frantically hasn't really helped me and I don't just want to look at the actual solution because where's the fun in that so here goes.

My thought process was the game should initially ask the player to input their guess and their bid, then run the code in game() and print the outcome. This was then to be locked in a while loop to check if the user wanted to continue playing or not and if the answer was "Yes" to restart the game() function again. This is where I am stuck as I just can't figure out what to put in line 26 after the "Yes" check returns True.

I guess the TL/DR version of my actual question is how do you (without giving the actual code away) call a function from within a while loop? Wondering if perhaps I'm simply headed in the wrong direction here and need to review while loops once more.

Thanks!

```
# Import stuff
import random
# Generate random number from 1 - 9
num = random.randint(1, 10)
# The actual game, asking user for input and returning the outcome
def game():
    guess = int(input("Guess the number: "))
    bid = int(input("Bet on the game: "))
    money = 100
    
    if guess == num:
        money = (money + bid)
        print("You Won")
        print("You now have: " + str(money) +" money")
        return money
    else:
        money = (money - bid)
        print("You lost, you will die poor")
        print("You now have: " + str(money) +" money")
        return money
# Run game() while there's still money left in the pot
def structure():
    while money > 0:
        another_go = input("Would you like to play again? Yes or No: ")
        if another_go == "Yes":
            game() # This is where I'm stuck 
        elif another_go == "No":
            print("Oh well, suit yourself")
            break
        else:
            print("Pick Yes or No")
            print(another_go)

game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so a few things to go through here.

First off, the concept of a `local` variable is coming into play here and is why your `money` variable is not communicating properly between your two functions. Each of your functions uses it's own `money` variable, which is completely independent of the other.

So this is the root of your current problem, where your `money > 0` loop never actually runs. Secondly, although this might have just been done for troubleshooting, you don't actually call `structure` which is supposed to control `game()`.

Lets try something like this where we keep `money` in the structure function and pass an update version to the game `function` as a `parameter`. Then, because you have `game()` returning `money`, you can just update the money value in your `structure()` call.

```py
# Import stuff
import random
# Generate random number from 1 - 9
num = random.randint(1, 10)
# The actual game, asking user for input and returning the outcome
def game(money):
    guess = int(input("Guess the number: "))
    bid = int(input("Bet on the game: "))
    
    if guess == num:
        money = (money + bid)
        print("You Won")
        print("You now have: " + str(money) +" money")
        return money
    else:
        money = (money - bid)
        print("You lost, you will die poor")
        print("You now have: " + str(money) +" money")
        return money

# Run game() while there's still money left in the pot
def structure():

    money = 100
    money = game(money)

    while money > 0:
        another_go = input("Would you like to play again? Yes or No: ")
        if another_go == "Yes":
            money = game(money) # This is where I'm stuck 
        elif another_go == "No":
            print("Oh well, suit yourself")
            break
        else:
            print("Pick Yes or No")
            print(another_go)


structure()
```

Notice because of how your `while` loop is written, in order to get `game()` to run the first time I had to call it before the `while` loop. Maybe as a challenge, see if you can be rewrite the structure of your loop so that you don't have to do this!

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for the feedback, exactly what I was asking for. Good to know I wasn't too far off either! Looks like while loops are going to need a re-read...

Comment: A helpful tip with while loops, if they are not working try printing the condition at the start of every loop for troubleshooting and you can usually work backwards from there to see why they aren't.

Comment: Oh cool, I'm going to try my hand at Cho - Han next, so this will definitely come in handy. Thanks for all the advice, small successes really help push you forward when just starting out.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Your code is overall fine. Here's one way to slightly change your code to make it work:

```
... Most of the code ... 

money  = 10

def structure():
    another_go = "Yes" # initialize to 'Yes', so we'll 
                       # always have a first game. 
    while money > 0:
        
        if another_go == "Yes":
            game() # This is where I'm stuck 
        elif another_go == "No":
            print("Oh well, suit yourself")
            break
        else:
            print("Pick Yes or No")
            print(another_go)
        # move 'another go' to the end of the loop
        another_go = input("Would you like to play again? Yes or No: ")            

structure() # call this function to start
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# make money a global parameter with a -ve value
money = -1

def game():
    global money
    guess = int(input("Guess the number: "))
    bid = int(input("Bet on the game: "))
    # Then, if money has default(game started for first time), update it
    if(money < 0):
        money = 100


.
.
.
.
while money > 0:
    global money
        another_go = input("Would you like to play again? Yes or No: ")
        if another_go == "Yes":
            game(money) # Pass remaining money to game() 
.
.
.
```